# How to Hash Passwords

Tags: .net, hash, cryptography

I found this example on MSDN: [How to Hash Passwords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602)

And these are the .NET Crypto classes: [HashAlgorithm Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As you can see, all (sub)classes are abstract. But the method signature in MSDN's code sample is built as:

```
string HashPassword(string clearData, string saltValue, HashAlgorithm hash)
```

So my question is, how can I use this code e.g. using MD5 Hashing Algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the implementation in the `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` class (this one is not abstract):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

You can instantiate it and pass as the `HashAlgorithm` parameter of the `HashPassword` function of your sample.